# in Laravel 8, how to make a status field with "failed" value, on unsuccessfull validation of data?

Tags: laravel, api, registration

in Laravel 8, how to make a status field with "failed" value, on unsuccessfull validation of data? The part that I cannot seem to extend, nor catch, that generates the response (which doesn't have the success field in it) is:

```
trait RegistersUsers {

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    ...
    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse(["status" => "success",
            "message" => "Registration successful",
            "user" => $user], 201)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath());
```

The response has this form:

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "username": [
      "The username has already been taken."
    ],
    "phone": [
      "The phone has already been taken."
    ]
  }
}
```

but I would like it to also have `status` field somehow. How do I go about setting this field? Thanks in advance for those who will do some of the idiotic downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can create a [manually validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators) method :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

         if($validator->fails()) {    
              return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'errors' => $validator->messages()], 200);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Tgank you, this does look like a good start, but could you please tell me more info on how to embed this code into the call. The call I am talking about is POST request to http://mywebsite.com/register
So RegisterController is handling it.

Comment: Just put it on your register controller

Comment: I updated the question. I need the response to be json, not a webpage.